# Variable inside inner interpolation

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

This one perfectly works:

```
($"SELECT * FROM {Table} WHERE Hex = 11 {(isConfirmed ? " AND UserId<>5" : string.empty)}";
```

Nevertheless besides static **5** value i want to put variable there. I tried to change as follows nevertheless something is wrong:

```
($"SELECT * FROM {Table} WHERE Hex = 11 {(isConfirmed ? " AND UserId<>"{myVariable} : string.empty)}";
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: `What i am doing wrong?` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM {Table} WHERE Hex = 11 {(isConfirmed ? $" AND UserId<>{myVariable}" : string.Empty)}";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add an interpolation character `$` before inner `" AND UserId<>{myVariable}"` string to use an interpolation expression inside this string

```cs
var isConfirmed = true;
var Table = "test";
var myVariable = 5;
var str = $"SELECT * FROM {Table} WHERE Hex = 11 {(isConfirmed ? $" AND UserId<>{myVariable}" : string.Empty)}";
```

It'll give you

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE Hex = 11  AND UserId<>5

Comment: Speculating, probably because it's the same as an answer posted two minutes earlier.

Comment: @GSerg First point - while posting and typing an answer I didn't check an updates of the page, second point -  a code explanation. According to the site rules code-only answers are not considered as a good ones